# Method returns wrong value because return is too early

Tags: java, methods, return, return-value

Sorry for that weird thread title but I didn't know how to describe my problem better than this.

I'm currently working on a Java project which uses the Microsoft Graph API (it's my first time that I'm using Microsoft Graph API).

I think my problem is a general problem with Java. I have a class which provides a Graph API client and a second class with all the operations I want to execute with the Graph API. The class with the operation methods should return the results to the client class.

Some code.
My Client class (relevant part where I call an operation):

```
client = GraphServiceClientManager.getInstance().getGraphServiceClient();
Operations task = new Operations(client);
System.out.println(task.getUsernamebyUPN("USER UPN"));
```

My class with the operations:

```
public String username = "0";

    public String getUsernamebyUPN(String UPN) {
       client.users(UPN).buildRequest().get(new ICallback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(User user) {
                username = user.displayName;

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        return username;
    }
```

So the problem is when I run the code it will return the username with value 0 instead of the username I want. The username variable will be changed after the return.

If I add a System.out.prntln(username) under the "username = user.displayName;" line in the success method my output would be:

```
0
The username I want
```

How can I solve this problem? Do you need more code?

Thank you very much for your help. :)

Comment: You can't return a value from a method that uses a call-back mechanism. Instead, make the changes desired in the callback itself. Either that or use some notification system to tell you when the call back occurs.

Comment: Maybe try: OperatorClassName.this.username=user.displayName;

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels since this is an anonymous class, according to: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html "An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class."

Comment: @Maryam: that only matters if the anonymous class has a field that is shadowing the variable. This one doesn't and so your suggestion adds no benefit whatsoever. The OP's code already does what your suggestion is telling him to do. The problem here is one of concurrency and not of variable reference.

Comment: Thank you for your fast replies.
@HovercraftFullOfEels Your post helped me, I think I fixed it, will test it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

The value will be returned asynchronously to the callback function, but you can force your program to wait the return when it needs the value. One way to do it is to return a value holder class that blocks when you try to get the value until it is set, and the callback sets the value.

For example, the following class users a Phaser to control this waiting behavior:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Phaser;

public class FutureValue<T> {

    private T value = null;
    private Exception ex = null;
    private Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1);

    /**
     * Get blocks until a value or an exception is set, after that it always
     * returns immediately
     *
     * @return the value
     * @throws ExecutionException
     */
    public T get() throws ExecutionException {
        phaser.register();
        phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance();
        if (ex != null) {
            throw new ExecutionException(ex);
        }
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value and unblocks awaiting threads
     *
     * @param val
     */
    public void set(T val) {
        this.value = val;
        phaser.forceTermination();
    }

    /**
     * Sets an exception and unblocks awaiting threads
     */
    public void setException(InterruptedException ex) {
        this.ex = ex;
        phaser.forceTermination();
    }
}
```

And you can change your method to return a FutureValue:

```java
    public FutureValue<String> getUsernamebyUPN(String UPN) {

       final FutureValue<String> future = new FutureValue<String>();
       client.users(UPN).buildRequest().get(new ICallback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void success(User user) {
                future.set(user.displayName);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(ClientException ex) {
                future.setException(ex);
            }
        });
        return future;
    }
```

Another option is to change your logic to not get the values, but observe events, with the callbacks sending the events.